# Django: How do I prepend

Tags: django, string

I'm exploring Django and got this particular problem.

How do I prepend `<span class="label">Note:</span>` inside `{{article.content_html|safe}}`?

The content of `{{article.content_html|safe}}` are paragraph blocks, and I just wanna add `<span class="label">Note:</span>` in the very first paragraph.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to write a [custom tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#howto-custom-template-tags) that uses [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML and inject the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way. You can easily prepend to all articles.

```
<span class="label">Note:</span>
{{article.content_html|safe}}
```

If that doesn't help you consider changing the structure of article.content_html so you can manipulate with blocks from django templates, so it should look something like this

```
{{article.content_header}}
<span class="label">Note:</span>
{{article.content_html}}
```

If that solution is not feasible to you and you absolutely need to parse and modify the content of article.content_html, write your own custom filter that does that. You can find documentation about writing custom filters here http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach could be to do this with javascript. In jQuery, it would look something like:

```
var first_p_text = $("p:first").text()
$("p:first").html("<span class="label">Note:</span>" + first_p_text)
```

Note though that if there are other elements inside your first p, $("p:first").text() will grab the text from those as well - see http://api.jquery.com/text/

Of course, this relies on decent javascript support in the client.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is the simplest and easiest to implement.  You only need one line with the prepend call ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)):

```
$('p:first').prepend('<span class="label">Note:</span>');
```

**Explanation:** *'p:first'* is a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) similar to the *':first-child'* [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp).  It will select the first paragraph and the prepend call will then insert the span into that selected paragraph.

**Note:** If there is a paragraph on the page before your content, you may have to surround it with a div:

```
<div id='ilovesmybbq'>{{article.content_html|safe}}</div>
```

Then the jQuery call would be:

```
$('#ilovesmybbq p:first').prepend('<span class="label">Note:</span>');
```

Comment: love how python questions get answered with jQuery. Nothing is immune.